# Caching images in a Microsoft Excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I have a Microsoft Excel 2013 Workbook project using Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) where I would like to have a mechanism for caching an image using a PictureBox. I have the caching mechanism working for textual data and a test scenario for an image that fails. The exception is: "Cannot deserialize cached item myCachedImage. Is this even possible for an image? Example below.

```
    [Cached]
    public string myCachedString;

    [Cached]
    public Image myCachedImage;

    private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.NeedsFill("myCachedString")) // Works fine.
        {
            textBox1.Text = myCachedString;
        }
        if (!this.NeedsFill("myCachedImage")) // Exception: Cannot deserialize cached item "myCachedImage".
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = myCachedImage;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a long winded way about this which is to serialise an image to string. Store as a string then retrieve it and reconstruct the image.

Credit to @Christian Liensberger from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/011c2c24-ffc5-4be5-883b-2430267b33c8/serialize-an-image-to-a-string?forum=Vsexpressvcs).

I welcome any other answers if any.